# c , passing char array as parameter in function?

Tags: c, arrays, char, arguments

```
 int check(int i,int j,char test);

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char mat[5][5];
    char *anahtar;
    anahtar=(char*)malloc (length*sizeof(char));
    //i take length from user with scanf

    int k=0;
    if (check(i,j,anahtar[k])==1)
    {
        mat[i][j]=anahtar[k];
    }

    int check(int i,int j,char test)
    {
        int a=0;
        int b=0;
        if (mat[a][b]==test)
        {
            return 1;                                
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

}

It gives error

```
undefined reference to `check'|
```

anahtar[] is a char array.So why cant i pass anahtar[k] in argument?

I already have protoype. PRoblem is not that.

Comment: Could you please edit your question in a more readable way?

Comment: you don't seem to have defined the function prototype before your main.
Then again, I don't even see where your main method starts

Comment: I put prototype but i did not want to paste all my code here to take your time more while reading

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `check` function is inside the `main`. Place it outside of `main`.

Also do not cast `malloc`;

```
anahtar = malloc (length*sizeof(char));
```

Comment: if i put function completely outside of main, i should put variables too.putting prototype outside is not enough?

Comment: Ater putting it outside you have to manage `if (mat[a][b]==test)`. `mat[a][b]` is not visible to `check`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare it before you use it or 
put this beforehand

> int check(int i,int j,char test);